# Jquery add class not working?

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.portfoliopod').on('click', function(){
    $('.portfoliopod').addClass('current');
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="portfoliopod">
<img class="portfolioimage" src="aboutme.jpg">
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">testing 123</div>
</div>
```

When I click the "portfolio pod" section the class "current" is not added. Am i missing something obvious here?

Comment: Is your jQuery within a document ready handler or at the end of the document? If it is, it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3xjqmuqg/

Comment: Think you may have answered my question. The jQUery is pulling in that section through PHP after the DOM has loaded. Is that why this is happening?

Comment: my javascript starts off like so: jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) { and all the code here. i guess this means it doesnt wait till its loaded?

Comment: @BenLiger Sounds like a case of event delegation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Could you please elaborate George?

Comment: Code looks fine, as j08691 has suggested, its most likely that at the time the script is run, the element does not yet exist. Wrap the code in a ready handler and it should work fine.

Comment: @BenLiger Yep, sorry. Was finding the link. Think its a duplicate.

Comment: Are you saying that the HTML is loaded after the page is loaded, like via AJAX? I'm unclear on your first comment.

Comment: So on click of a button the portoflio is loaded through PHP

Comment: Read up on .on()'s event delegation syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As OP said "on click of a button the portoflio is loaded through PHP", I assume the portfolio content is loaded via **AJAX**. So, you have to use this to listen the event on the element :

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.portfoliopod', function(){
    jQuery('.portfoliopod').addClass('current');
});
```

As the `.portfoliopod` element is a dynamically created element, the code you're currently using won't bind the event to element that is going to come in the DOM tree later.

So, the way of binding the listener is to bind it on `document` and check if the element clicked on `document` is `.portfoliopod`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

Also, it seems like on your site, `$` is undefined (very strange). So, use `jQuery` instead.

Or, if you want the `$` object, add this code at the very end of your jQuery file before `})(window);` :

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Comment: Probably want `$(document).on('click',` not `$('.portfoliopod').on('click',` if `portfoliopod` is part of what's loaded dynamically.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Heres the site if it helps at all:http://benliger.webatu.com/

Comment: Makes perfect sense, Thats a lot @Subin

Answer (score 0):

check it by using this code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfoliopod">
<img class="portfolioimage" src="aboutme.jpg">
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">testing 123</div>
</div>
<script>
$('.portfoliopod').on('click', function(){
    $('.portfoliopod').addClass('current');
});</script>
```

if this code works then , the fault is with the inclution of jquery script.

Comment: I tried adding your script at the start of the PHP page its loading in and i still get nothing

Comment: kindly verify by "inspect element " on click on <div class="portfoliopod"> the class name is added and the result is <div class="portfoliopod current">